# Formatting tip says 4 spaces are needed for nested lists when it appears to be 3

Tags: bug, markdown, editor, markdown-preview

It looks like I was able to make a nested list by using 3 spaces (and then 2 spaces for each additional nested list), even though the formatting tip says "4 or 8 spaces" are required. See image below.

[image: nested lists in editor]

Here is the markdown I used:

```
1. test
   - test
     - test
```

Here is a live example:

1. test

   - test

     - test

So either the tips are wrong or the markdown renderer is not working correctly.

Comment: It appears to work with 3–6 spaces for the first item, and extra 2–5 spaces per each additional nested item (not just multiples of 3).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek You're right. I updated the question to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: @KodosJohnson there is a sandbox to test the kind of things you tried in your now deleted answer.